# Is the physiology-to-sound function injective, and if so, why?

Tags: phonetics

By injective, I mean that there are no inputs corresponding to the same output. I only recently learned that the range of sounds produced by human physiology has to do with different mouth positions changing the resonance of the mouth, I think. These resonances are called “formants”.

The anatomy-to-sound function is not surjective, because arguably, no human can reasonably be expected to be able to produced every possible sound.

However, what if there were two distinct ways of producing the same sound/formants?

Is there a clear argument why it is mechanically impossible?

For example: since there is only one mouth, it would require distinct changes in mouth position having the same sound. Then geometrically, if we can think of the mouth more abstractly, the question might be if there are multiple ways of expressing a certain geometry in a mouth shape. For example, let’s say elongating the mouth by rounding the lips and making an “ooo” sound causes there to be longer soundwaves inside the mouth. Maybe we could at least ask hypothetically, what if the cheeks could narrow or widen perpendicular to that axis?

That wouldn’t be a great example tho. I am pretty sure it can be proven that given the geometric properties of the mouth it is impossible to have two positions produce the same resonance, but I’d like to see that proof.

Comment: Not sure geometry is a good word here. Shape of the mouth and sounds.